# Combining ArrayList<String> and ArrayList<Integer> into One Adapter and List View

Tags: java, android, adapter

```
    ArrayList<String> stepsList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> stepsPosList = new ArrayList<>();

 stepsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.steps_item,R.id.etStepsDetails,stepsList);
    stepsAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,R.layout.steps_item,R.id.tvStepsPosition,stepsPosList);


    stepsView.setAdapter(stepsAdapter);
    stepsView2.setAdapter(stepsAdapter2);
```

Is it possible to combine the 2 array adapter into 1? The layout is on the same page but I need 2 id and 2 array list into each. and then call the list view.

POJO CLASS

```
public class CombineData {

ArrayList<String> stepsList;
ArrayList<Integer> stepsPosList;

public CombineData(ArrayList<String> stepsList,ArrayList<Integer> stepsPosList){
    this.stepsList = stepsList;
    this.stepsPosList = stepsPosList;
}

public CombineData(){

}

public ArrayList<String> getStepsList() {
    return stepsList;
}

public void setStepsList(ArrayList<String> stepsList) {
    this.stepsList = stepsList;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getStepsPosList() {
    return stepsPosList;
}

public void setStepsPosList(ArrayList<Integer> stepsPosList) {
    this.stepsPosList = stepsPosList;
}
```

}

THIS LINE SHOWS AN ERROR : CANNOT RESOLVE CONSTRUCTOR ARRAYADAPTER... int,int,ArrayList

```
        stepsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CombineData>(this,R.layout.steps_item,R.id.etStepsDetails,stepsList);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you should make POJO class

```
class CombineData(
    ArrayList<String> stepsList,
    ArrayList<Integer> stepsPosList
)
{
getter()/setter()      
}
```

then change adapter

```
  stepsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CombineData>(this,R.layout.steps_item,R.id.etStepsDetails,stepsList);
```

Now, you can access in the listview  like this

```
    item.stepsList
    item.stepsPosList
```

Comment: Sorry but I am a beginner. Im not quite sure how to do it fully. Can you show me a more detailed coding? Thanks

Comment: This is a nice use case for Generics. If you're new to Java/Kotlin, I would highly recommend reading about it

Comment: I have created the POJO class. but the adapter is not working yet.